# How to use same scale transform on all textblocks in a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

so I have an nx3 grid full of several textblocks, and I was wondering if there is a relatively simple way to apply the same scale transform on all the textblocks so they end up with the same font.

Not sure how to go about this, but I was thinking maybe. Viewbox all of the textboxes to their grid slot. Select the smallest scalefactor that was applied. Apply the scaletransform to all the textblocks.

Anyway, Is there any other way I could get the max scale transform that can be applied to the text while keeping it within its grid slot?

It might be easier to just have a font size option and use grid splitters, but autoscalability sounds nice

Comment: Um, what are you trying to do exactly? Is FontSize not enough? Not sure exactly the effect you're going for here man.

Comment: I just want the fontsize to scale to the maximum font size that will not make an item too large to fit in its grid space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Viewbox all of the textboxes to their grid slot.

Sounds viable, you can use an `ItemsControl` with a `Grid` as panel and put the `Viewbox` into the `ItemTemplate`. You would need to bind it to a collection of objects that contain the text and row/column info so you can bind the `Grid.Row`/`Column` in the `ItemContainerStyle`.